# Why is cordova.file.applicationDirectory null?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am trying to build my Cordova / AngularJS application and here is my initialization:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents()
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false)
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].setAttribute("href", cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/");
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"])
    }
};
app.initialize()
```

However, `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` is null. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact a Cordova app is an APK application. `/www` folder becomes a logical address in your application after you build it.

And `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` function gives your application's folder address on your device.

Your Application contains `/res, /www, /js` folders and plugins. You can reach just when you give a source address like `src = "../res/home.png"`

Comment: Is this the same for `iOS`? Also, why would `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` be null?

Comment: I have never developed for IOS. But it has to same. Eventually Cordova builds (convert) HTML5 codes to a native app. Good luck.